# Why doesn't Visual Studio display the print out function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm learning C++ online and working with Visual Studio Community 2019 (version 16.7.2). Sometimes it displays errors or weird results despite using the exact same code as the one the tutor used. Take the code below for instance. It should print out to the console but it doesn't. Instead, it shows an empty console when I run it on my end. What could be the problem? The teacher is also using Visual Studio on a Windows machine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void printSomething();

int main()
{
    printSomething;
    return 0;
}

void printSomething()
{
    cout << "Hey! Over here." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are only "mentioning" it here `printSomething;`.
To actually call it try the appropriate operator `()` as in `printSomething();`.

Comment: We should have a dup for this.  It happens over and over.

Comment: True. Itchy fingers. Find one and close it, I will help and take the dupe into my library. If it gets deleted as non-signpost it is fine with me. @PaulSanders

Comment: For me, this is a typo, the warnings are very clear about this -> warning C4551: function call missing argument list

Comment: I agree :p The worst is that this warning is there without any additional flags.

Comment: No pb, that's gold badge privilege :D